# Can I revert back to 14+ from 15 on an old machine?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, firefox, restore, downgrade

So many problems with the new release, my reps and system is fighting them like a virus?

Using Lubuntu 15.04
2g cpu with 1027 mem

I know it is slow but still makes no sense why it takes so long to load stuff. I really only use this machine for youtube or documents (at work, heh).

Can I revert back, or do I need to format? Is there a trick I am missing?

All my repositories are updated and I cleared all the add-ons and what-nots from Firefox (chrome or similar uses too much memory for my system).

Answer (score 4):

There is no officially supported way to downgrade. Anyway, it would be buggy. You will eventually spend less time to reinstall.